# How to order localStorage by KEY ASC?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I save data to localStorage.
To be able to order the localStorage i use milliseconds as key.
(But localStorage doesn't sort or order, so i need to build a array or object that i can sort by key)

```
var key = Date.now();
var value = { 
    "id": id,
    "name": name
};

//ADD DATA TO OBJECT
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
```

Now i'd like to fetch localStorage and display the data ordered by key asc.

I tried:

```
//CONSOLE LOG LOCALSTORAGE
Storage {1614866637849: "{"id":"1","name":"A"}", 1614866687890: "{"id":"3","name":"C"}", 1614866642078: "{"id":"2","name":"B"}", length: 3}

//DECLARE NEW OBJ
var items = {};
    
//LOOP THREW localStorage
Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function(key){

    //FETCH THIS ROUND DATA
    items[key] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
});
 
//CONSOLE LOG ITEMS
1614866637849: {…}, 1614866687890: {…}, 1614866642078: {…}}
    
//SORT ITEMS
var sorted_items = Object.keys(items).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {accumulator[currentValue] = items[currentValue]; return accumulator;}, {});
    
//CONSOLE LOG SORTED ITEMS
1614866637849: {…}, 1614866687890: {…}, 1614866642078: {…}}
```

So it looks like my ordering function does nothing?
How can i loop out my data from localStorage by key ASC?

The order i wan't is:
....49
....78
....90

Comment: Have you tried: `Object.keys(localStorage).sort().forEach`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl No, not until now. But it seems to work?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and smartest way was commented by @Mr.polywhirl

Just add .sort() in the forEach:

```
Object.keys(localStorage).sort().forEach(function(key){..
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just print the results in key order, just `sort` the keys before calling `forEach`.

```js
Object.keys(localStorage).sort().forEach...
```

If you want sorted "pairs", because key order is not guaranteed, you can try the following.

```js
const storage =  {
  1614866637849: '{"id":"1","name":"A"}',
  1614866687890: '{"id":"3","name":"C"}',
  1614866642078: '{"id":"2","name":"B"}'
};

const pairs = Object.entries(storage)
  .map(([key, value]) => ({
    key: parseInt(key),
    value: JSON.parse(value)
  }))
  .sort(({ key: keyA }, { key: keyB }) => keyA - keyB);
  
console.log(pairs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

`Object.entries(YOUROBJECT).sort().reduce( (o,[k,v]) => (o[k]=v,o), {} );`

Your example:

```js
var yourdata = {1614866637849:{"id":"1","name":"A"}, 1614866687890:{"id":"3","name":"C"}, 1614866642078:{"id":"2","name":"B"}, length: 3};
console.log("BEFORE", yourdata);
console.log("NOW", Object.entries(yourdata).sort().reduce( (o,[k,v]) => (o[k]=v,o), {} ));
```

Result:

```
1614866637849: {id: "1", name: "A"}
1614866642078: {id: "2", name: "B"}
1614866687890: {id: "3", name: "C"}
```

Credit goes to:
[Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)
@sravan ganji